# can we use here binomial expansion?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

since$(1+x)^n =\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}(^n_r)x^{n-r}$.

We can expand $(a+x)^n $ by using binomial expansion if $n$ is any positive integer , but how can we expand if $n$ is a negative integer.

Comment: in differential equation of higher order , to find particular integral for algebraic functions , we reduce the differential co-efficient to (a+D)^(-n) form . so what will be its expansion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem with negative integers. Denote $-n= \alpha$ and use the definition of the binomial coefficient.
$$
\binom{-n}{k}= \binom{\alpha}{k}=\alpha \cdot (\alpha-1) \cdots (\alpha-k+1)\cdot \frac{1}{k!}=(-n)\cdot(-n-1) \cdots (-n-k+1)\cdot \frac{1}{k!}=(-1)^k\frac{(n-k+1)!}{(n-1)!k!}=(-1)^k \binom{n+k-1}{k}
$$

Comment: This is even true for any real value of $α$, not only integers.

Comment: Yes that's true

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $a\neq 0$, write $(x+a)^n$ as $a^n(1+x/a)^n$ then for $|x/a|<1$ we can expand it using binomial theorem. $$(x+a)^n= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\binom{n}{i}a^{n-i}x^{i}$$